# How to store a record of 20000 table rows in Web Browser localstorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have a task to store all the records to browsers local storage and display it in which I have to use it for searching sorting the data and display the result in the viewport.
  I am preferring to use WebSql but it does not have support for all browsers.
  I am looking for guidance to implement it but in then it cannot affect the performance of the browser while searching or sorting it.

I tried using websql

var result, name, version, display_name, size

```
name         = 'listofdata'
version      = 1.0
display_name = 'listofdata'
size         = 2621440 

// parameters: name, version, display name, size (in bytes)
db = window.openDatabase(name, version, display_name, size)

result = 'Database "' + display_name + '" created'
addResult(result, createDB)
```

I want to handle in other browsers too but no idea about it.

Comment: You'll need to consider the storage limit (~5MB) in the browser and will need to consider the use of IndexDB. In terms of performance, you'll want to consider the use of Web Workers (sub-processes) to process the data outside the main process. Good luck.

Comment: [IndexedDB is supported, more or less, across the breadth of modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure your 20K records are able to fit in the 5MB storage limit of `localStorage`.

Now coming to:

> I am looking for guidance to implement it but in then it cannot affect the performance of the browser while searching or sorting it.

***First approach:*** For sorting and searching, your best bet (logically and performance wise) would be to store all records into a single `JSON` stringified array into the `localStorage`, and then using `.filter()` and `.sort()` methods of the `Array` object to search and sort through them respectively. **Keep in mind that traversing through 20K records might take a few seconds** (1-4 seconds or so, depending on the processing power of the machine). This approach will be handy if you want to access and process all records at once.

***Second approach:*** Store each record individually using some sort of primary / unique key to identify each one of them. Then as and when required, just fetch the required one as you would normally fetch any key-value pair from localStorage. As for searching and sorting, you can use `Object.keys()` and `Object.entries()` to get all the records pretty quickly and then use the same `.filter()` and `.sort()` methods to search and sort as mentioned in first approach.

You don't necessarily have to use `indexeddb` or `SQL` database. **It IS achievable using `localStorage`**, just that it might only be apt for small records and in scenarios where scaling up will most likely never happen.